# Load files into Photoshop layers as vector smart objects

Tags: photoshop, adobe-bridge

Bridge is packaged with a script that will load multiple files as their own layer in a Photoshop file. There are two problems when you do this with a vector file:

1. It converts the files to raster layers. And since you don't get to choose the size of the file beforehand, if they're too small, you can't scale them up without losing quality.
2. It doesn't preserve antialiasing, leaving ugly jagged edges on whatever art you imported.

Is there a way to import multiple files into Photoshop as vector smart objects? Then you'd have full control over the quality. Alternatively, is there a way to define the size of the vector files you're loading into layers and/or preserve their antialiasing?

I found a [script](https://www.yktravelphoto.com/blog/scripts-and-automation/load-files-as-smart-objects-into-photoshop-layers) that loads files into Photoshop as smart objects, but this has the same two problems the factory Bridge script has. It appears to do the exact same thing, but converts the layers to smart objects after they are imported.

The only way I currently know of to get vector smart objects into Photoshop is to do so manually one by one by copying from Illustrator or by dragging the files to an open Photoshop file. I'm looking for a way to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid doing it manually is the only way to get where you want to go. I've wrestled with this same issue for years and hope with every PS/Bridge update they'll add the option to load a stack of smart objects, but so far it's still old-school drag n' drop.

Hit the Adobe suggestion box... maybe with enough requests they'll finally add this as a native feature.